# With VB what does putting "()" after a word do?

Tags: vb.net

what does putting "()" after a word do? sometimes it doesn't work

Comment: How do you use it. my instructor uses it and it works fine for him. I use it and stuffs every thing up.

Comment: Edit your question, and give us an example of it "stuffing everything up" :) Also, is it VB.Net, Vb6, VBScript, VBA or other . . .

Comment: I'm using VB 2008 express. When i use it to make a new sub it gets the blue line and an underline of the last letter.

Comment: Add your sub to your question, I can't tell you exactly whats wrong with it until I see the peice of code your having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what Mehrdad said:

The following lines use "()" to declare arrays:

```
'dynamic array w/o pre-set length'
Dim Doubles() As Double

'array of length 11'
Dim Doubles(10) As Double

'array of Strings initialized with three items'
Dim Strings() As New String() {"String1", "String2", "String3"}
```

The following line does NOT declare an array:

```
'here the "()" are treated as a call to the MyObject constructor'
Dim MyObjects As New MyObject()
```

Answer (score 10):

**Methods**

If you look at Console.WriteLine, the commonly used forms of this method take one or more arguements e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
```

However, one overload takes no parameters, and simply prints a blank line

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

Empty Braces show a method call with no arguements.

**Arrays**

```
Dim s as String ' declares one string
Dim as(10) as string ' declares 11 strings, accessed by position
```

The following both declare variables that will later be assigned an array of strings.

```
Dim n() as string
Dim m as string()
```

Answer (score 2):

It calls a method. It's also used to declare an array, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The paranthesis are there for function or method calls.  For example, if you have a method named Run you would call it by saying MyDog.Run()

Properties and regular variables are different and do not use paranthesis.  For example, MyDog.FurColor = Blue

Some functions take parameters.  Taking our example, a parameter might be how far to run.  So, MyDog.Run(10)

But, given your other questions you probably already know the answer to this one...

Answer (score 0):

We use () with words which are 1) methods or 2) functions or 3) Sub-routines or 4) procedures etc.

Also arrays use it.

Method = An action that can be performed by an object. In Visual Basic .NET, methods are defined as Subs and Functions.